# WebView and AppBar for Desktop PCs

Tags: webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, appbar

I'm using a WebView control in my app, and it takes all the screen in both width and height. I use the "WebBrush workaround" to be able to display the AppBar and other controls in front of the WebView when needed.

For the AppBar it's working when using a tablet and swiping from the bottom or the top of the device. But on a desktop when clicking the right button of the mouse, the AppBar are disappearing almost at the same time they are appearing.

Does a trick/workaround exist to be able to support this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample for the WebView contains a scenario with a full screen WebView and the AppBar. The hack is to resize the WebView when the AppBar opens.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7